# Comparing two concepts within statistics

Tags: statistics

I need to clarify a concept. Mathematically speaking, are the following two concepts equivalent?

**Concept A**: In statistics, if an outcome has a $25$% chance of occurrence, this implies that one can expect the said occurrence to materialize once within, on average, $\frac{1}{0.25} = 4$ trials.

**Concept B**: According to psychology's [reinforcement theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement#Simple_schedules), a behavior is said to follow a 'variable reward' (VR) schedule if it's reinforced, on average, at every nth response - but not always on the nth response. E.g. lab example: VR $4$ => first pellet delivered on $2$ bar presses, second pellet delivered on 6 bar presses, third pellet 4 bar presses ($2 + 6 + 4 = 12$ or $\frac{12}{3}= 4$ bar presses to receive pellet).

Comment: The mention of $0.4$ in the denominator in **Concept A** seems misplaced.  While "four" as a mathematical concept seems to be shared between **A** and **B**, I would be hard put to extend the parallelism of these "concepts" too far beyond that.  It doesn't seem like a clarification of a concept.

Comment: $1/0.4\neq 4$, FYI

Comment: @TheCount: was a typo, fixed it.

Comment: @hardmath: the 0.4 was a typo, fixed it. This is a cross-domain question: one's a simple statistics concept, the other a mathematical representation of a theory borrowed from Human Psychology. My question is regarding whether the VR schedules merely describe a simple probability function, or whether there could be cases where these concepts diverge.

Comment: In A there is random chance, but the laws of probability hold. In B, there may be random behavior in rats' brains and experimental psychologists can (and do) debate whether 'reinforcement theory' is a valid theory and whether randomized rewards are more effective than systematic ones.

Comment: @BruceET: Thanks, this helps.